# Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}=0$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{s_{n}}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}=0$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{s_{n}}=0$

Please check my proof and point the mistake

If sequence is converge and $\epsilon > 0$

we have $|S_{n}-0|<\epsilon$ 
Then we must prove $|\sqrt{S_{n}}-0|< \epsilon $for every $n>K$ is true

Because $\lim_{}s_{n}=0\Rightarrow s_{n} < \epsilon $

then

$$ \sqrt{S_{n}}< \sqrt{\epsilon } $$

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{S_{n}}}$$

then we choose $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\leq K$

Because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\leq K$ and $K<n \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}<n$

therefore $|\sqrt{S_{n}}-0|$ for every $n>K$ 
that is limit of $\sqrt{S_{n}}$ equal 0

Comment: @DavidBowman Sure: that $(s_n)$ is nonnegative.

Comment: You could prove something stronger, that if $f$ is a continuous functions and $x_n$ converges, then $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$

Comment: @frusciante14 I just read one-half section 2 about sequence in real analysis book I didn't know about it yet.But thank you for help  ^ ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're argument is not valid, I'm afraid: you're basically proving that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{s_n}=0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=0$.

It is implicitly assumed that $s_n\ge0$ and you should write in a better way the statements.

> Given $\varepsilon>0$ we need to find $K$ such that, for $n>K$, $|\sqrt{s_n}|<\varepsilon$.

The inequality $\sqrt{s_n}<\varepsilon$ is equivalent to $s_n<\varepsilon^2$.

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=0$, there exists $K$ such that, for $n>K$, $s_n<\varepsilon^2$. Then $\sqrt{s_n}<\varepsilon$.